# HTML file using Jquery DataTables will load from file but not from IDE: $(...)DataTable is not a function error

Tags: datatables

I have a short test html file in which I include the Jquery Plugin DataTables. If I open the html file from the desktop into Chrome or Safari or another browser, it works. If however, I try to launch the file from within an IDE (like Xpages or Coda), I get the error $(...)DataTable is not a function.

I have included the Jquery library first, so I am baffled at to what the problem is.

The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script>
    body {
    font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
        }
</script>

<script>    
    $(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
} );



    </script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can it happen because your style is wrapped into <script>? Was it done intentionally? Please try to remove your body style, because it has a wrong format. In your code sample: <script>
    body {
    font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
        }
</script>

Comment: OK I think I would like to erase this question.........

Comment: Actually, probably not. I did change the script to style. It then worked in Coda. But the exact same code put into the Xpages IDE failed. I get the same error $(...)DataTable is not a function.....

Comment: Your code works fine after replacing `script` with `style`, see https://jsfiddle.net/acjkwg4c/

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove your body style, first, because it has a wrong format. In your code sample:

```
<script>
    body {
    font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
        }
</script>
```

The second thing I see is a strange error message: "$(…)DataTable is not a function" there is no point symbol after $(…).

Comment: I have removed the body style completely, and again it works fine in Coda but not in Xpages IDE. It must be something within the IDE I think,